# How to limit decimal places to only four in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, decimal

I'm making a temperature slider but the output keeps on displaying 15 or so digits after the decimal place. How do I resolve this and have it display only 4 numbers after the decimal place?

```
import UIKit

class TemperatureViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fahrenheitLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var celsiusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var kelvinLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureSlider: temperatureSlider!
    var temperature:Measurement<UnitTemperature> {
        let fahrenheitValue = Measurement<UnitTemperature>(value: Double(temperatureSlider.value), unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
        return fahrenheitValue
    }
    @IBAction func sliderChange(_ sender: Any) {
        updateTemperatureDisplay()
    }
    func updateTemperatureDisplay() {
        celsiusLabel.text = temperature.description
        fahrenheitLabel.text = temperature.converted(to: .fahrenheit).description
        kelvinLabel.text = temperature.converted(to: .kelvin).description
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        updateTemperatureDisplay()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, you should make use of the available formatters.  The measurements API provides a [`MeasurementFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter) which is a good place to start

```
let celsius = Measurement<UnitTemperature>(value: 10.91235, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
let fahrenheit = celsius.converted(to: .fahrenheit)

let mf = MeasurementFormatter()
mf.unitOptions = .providedUnit

mf.string(from: celsius)
mf.string(from: fahrenheit)
```

So the above example basically outputs

```
10.91235 °C // original
51.64222999999585 °F // converted

10.912°C
51.642°F
```

If you need more control, you can supply your own `NumberFormatter` to  `MeasurementFormatter`

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 4
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

let mf = MeasurementFormatter()
mf.numberFormatter = numberFormatter
mf.unitOptions = .providedUnit
```

Comment: No need to instantiate a new number formatter

Comment: @LeoDabus In this case, that’s probably true, but it’s a decent enough example if you already have one configured

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `Double` (and use it throughout your app if this is an operation you need done elsewhere):

```
extension Double {

    func truncate(places: Int) -> Double {
        return Double(floor(pow(10.0, Double(places)) * self)/pow(10.0, Double(places)))
    }

}

let rawValue = 51.64222999999585
let formattedValue = rawValue.truncate(places: 4)

print(formattedValue) // 51.6422
```